# Binary python libraries for Mac

Tags: python, macos

Is there an equivalent for Mac OS to [Christoph Golke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) that hosts precompiled python libraries ?

I know that on Unix the wheels format is not yet supported, but Mac OS does support it. I don't own a Mac, but are there any technical limitations to making the equivalent for Mac ? Or is it just a matter of one person deciding to do it ?

I am curious, because I would like to find a more streamlined and robust way to install binary python package on Mac. I have multiple Mac users that cannot use a pure python package I developed because they are facing installation issues of pyqt (that my package depends on), using homebrew.

Comment: I don't know of any central repository like that, sadly. Individual packages often have pre compiled binaries (installed as .pkg files). Python on Mac is complicated by the fact that users often have multiple installations - system Python, Python.org Python, and MacPorts/Homebrew Python.

Comment: Have a look at anaconda. https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda

Comment: Well, for myself, I can use anaconda. But I cannot require my users to install an entire anaconda distribution. Or should I ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) is most likely the best solution.

It works flawlessly accross OSes, and is smaller in terms of size than the original Anaconda.